# View response headers before they are sent to the client?

Tags: java, jsp, debian, tomcat5.5

I am writing a project for school.  I want to be able to display, on a web page, the response headers that the web server sent to the client.  I am able to read request headers from HttpServletRequest and am able to write response headers to HttpServletResponse no problem.

Is there any way to do this?  It is possible to make a copy of what the server is about to send?

I am using Eclipse Helios to develop this JSP with POJOs application, and am using Tomcat 5.5 running on Debian Lenny to serve it.

Thanks,

Ean

Comment: Can you explain why you need to know the headers before they are sended?

Comment: Ok, this sounds good.  One (hopefully minor) problem remains: the doFilter method defines a ServletResponse res as follows:

`code`
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
`/code`

...in which, I cast the ServletResponse as an HttpServletResponse so that I can access methods like getHeader(), etc.:

`code`
HttpServletResponse response =(HttpServletResponse) res;
`/code`

...but, I still only have access to the methods from ServletResponse, not those from HttpServletResponse.

Any thoughts as to why?

Ean

Comment: just cast to `HttpServletResponse`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `Filter` and an `HttpServletResponseWrapper`.

Override the three `addXHeader(..)` methods with something like:

```
void addHeader(String name, String value) {
   super.addHeader(name, value);
   getWriter().write(name + " : " + value);
}
```

And then, in a `Filter`:

```
chain.doFilter(request, new HeaderHttpServletResponseWrapper(response));
```

But I would use Firebug to check headers.

Or [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231/accessing-http-headers-in-javascript) (the 2nd answer)

Comment: @Bozho: where are the three addXHeaer methods?  So far I just have a filter with doFilter, init, and destroy.  Thanks!

Comment: In your `HttpServletResponseWrapper` implementation.

Comment: @Bozho: looking at this a bit more, I'm not sure this is quite what I'm asking.  What I want to do is read the response headers, not write to them.  So, wherever addXHeader() is, I wouldn't be using it anyway.  Regarding Firebug, normally that is exactly what I would use as well, but the point of this exercise is to show that data on the web page.  thanks again.

Comment: @ean - you can't read them, you can only intercept when they are being written.

Comment: Just append them to some list instead which you expose by a public getter in your `HttpServletResponseWrapper` implementation which you **can** cast back later :)

Comment: Firstly, let me say thanks for the suggestions, I now have a filter that writes out every time a response header is written.  Unfortunately, this filter only "sees" the headers that I add, e.g. `code` response.addHeader("test","123"); `code`.  It doesn't catch all the ones that the server writes, i.e. Date, Server, Content-Length, Content-Type, Set-Cookie, Cache-Control, etc.  Is there a way to push the "order" of this filter so that it can see these headers, or does Tomcat just write those too late for me to access them?

Comment: @ean - isn't a client-side solution an option?

Comment: Yes it is an option, esp since this approach seems to have hit a dead end.  :)  I suppose I could write a java applet that would load in the page?  What would you suggest?

Comment: @ean http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231/accessing-http-headers-in-javascript (the 2nd answer)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to write a servlet filter which can intercept both the request and response before it gets sent.

Comment: If @ean wants for educational purpouse and hasty, he can also use a simple sniffer as ngrep.